# gitignore extension-less files from ONE directory

Tags: c++, git, github, executable, gitignore

I want to ignore all extension-less files (c++ executables) from one directory in my repository.
The file structure is something like this:

```
|--REPO
|   |--CPP
|   |   |--dir1
|   |   |    |--code1.cpp
|   |   |    |--executable1
|   |   |--dir2
|   |   |    |--code2.cpp
|   |   |    |--executable2
|   |--otherStuff
```

What I tried:

```
**/CPP/**/*
!**/CPP/**/*.*
!**/CPP/**/*/
```

But it doesn't ignore the executables.

Comment: That's not "from one directory": the directories involved here are `CPP/dir1` and `CPP/dir2`, and those are two directories. That aside, remember that `.gitignore` does not mean "ignore" (it really means "do not complain about untracked and do not auto-add untracked", which in turn means if they're already tracked, the listing in the `.gitignore` has no effect), and see the related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try add to .gitignore

```
**/CPP/*
**/CPP/*.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tabs at the beginning of those lines and after removing them it worked.